# Bitmap Morph Tween in Actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, bitmap, effect

How do you do a bitmap morph tween in Actionscript?  I would like to morph a Panel into a Button, using BitmapData or something but I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Fading+resizing will be a simple solution. Any tweening library, like [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/), [Tweenlite](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenliteas3/) will do the job. In this case the Button will be usable after transition too.

If you mean real [image morphing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphing), sorry I haven't seen any as3 library for that yet.

Comment: cool, I figured I should just do that, I'm realizing image morphing would require you to probably define "morphing points" and such, which is a little too much. Here's an example of one: incomplet.gskinner.com/index2.html#morph

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a 3rd party morph program and embed the video into Flash.